# How to use IPython 2.3.1 using StarCluster in stead of 0.13.1?

Tags: ipython, starcluster

StarCluster seems to use IPython 0.13.1 by default.  Is there a way to upgrade this to IPython 2.3.1?  Can it be done via the config file?  Or manually after the cluster is started?

Here is my config, with only minor security changes:

```
[global]
DEFAULT_TEMPLATE=iptemplate
REFRESH_INTERVAL=5

[aws info]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_region_name = us-west-2
aws_region_host = ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

[keypair starcluster]
key_location = starcluster.pem

[plugin ipcluster]
SETUP_CLASS = starcluster.plugins.ipcluster.IPCluster
ENABLE_NOTEBOOK = True
NOTEBOOK_PASSWD = XXXX

[plugin ipclusterstop]
SETUP_CLASS = starcluster.plugins.ipcluster.IPClusterStop

[plugin ipclusterrestart]
SETUP_CLASS = starcluster.plugins.ipcluster.IPClusterRestartEngines

[plugin pypackages]
setup_class = starcluster.plugins.pypkginstaller.PyPkgInstaller
packages = scikit-learn, psutil, pandas

# Base configuration for IPython.parallel cluster
[cluster iptemplate]
KEYNAME = starcluster
CLUSTER_SIZE = 1
CLUSTER_USER = ipuser
CLUSTER_SHELL = bash
#REGION = us-east-1
NODE_IMAGE_ID = ami-706afe40     # REGION and NODE_IMAGE_ID go in pair
NODE_INSTANCE_TYPE = c1.xlarge   # 8 CPUs
DISABLE_QUEUE = True             # We don't need SGE, faster cluster startup
PLUGINS = pypackages, ipcluster
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by updating [setup.py](https://github.com/jtriley/StarCluster/blob/50894f517837eb6b9a68f3e45ac7649e9c78c467/setup.py#L68). Add "ipython==2.3.1" to install_requires and rerun the setup command. It will update ipython to the version specified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that seems to only install IPython 2.3.1 in the local environment.  How can I get StarCluster to run IPython 2.3.1 on the EC2 machines?

Comment: Two options: 1-Install the ipython 2.3.1 on the machines once they are started. 2-Create a new AMI with that version of ipython and use it with StarCluster.

Comment: Thanks again for your input.  If I do option 1, how do I get the notebooks up and running the same way they were before the upgrade?

What I've tried so far is to do so far is to upgrade ipython on each node, and then run "starcluster runplugin ipclusterrestart  mycluster" (see above config), and it restarts the engines successfully, but gives me a 500 error when I try to access the notebook.